# Negating "If no one is absent, then if the weather permits, we will study outside"

Tags: logic

I am a beginner; please help solve this.

> Write the negation of the statement:
>
> "If no one is absent, then if the weather permits, we will study
> outside."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, write the statement as a logical statement (with appropriate notation).

A: "No one is absent."

W: "Weather permits"

S: "We will study outside."

Then we have the proposition, symbolically: 
$$A\rightarrow(W \rightarrow S)$$

Then, since we want to negate the proposition, we work with:

$$\begin{align} \lnot\Big(A\rightarrow(W \rightarrow S)\Big)& \equiv \lnot\Big(\lnot A \lor (\lnot W \lor S)\Big)\tag{$p\rightarrow q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$}\\ \\ & \equiv A \land W \land \lnot S\tag{DeMorgan's}\end{align}$$

So the negation of the statement translated back to English gives us:

> "No one is absent and weather is permitting, but (and) we won't study outside."

Comment: You do such a nice job with these! +1

Comment: I love study outside. :+)

Answer (score 1):

p="no one is absent"
q="the weather permits"
r="we will study outside"
$$\neg(p\to(q\to r))$$
$$\neg(\neg p \vee (q\to r))$$
$$(\neg \neg p) \wedge \neg(q\to r)$$
$$p \wedge \neg(\neg q \vee r)$$
$$p\wedge ((\neg \neg q)\wedge (\neg r))$$
$$p\wedge q\wedge (\neg r)$$

No one is absent and the weather permits and we will not study outside.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of $A\to B$ is $A\land\neg B$, so

> No one is absent and not (if the wheather permits, we will study outside)

Do the same for the second part to obtain

> No one is absent and the wheather permits and we will not study outside.

If you like, replace "no one is absent" with "everybody is present".